# Recording the screen during boot UEFI BIOS on Thinkpad T14s

Tags: bios, hdmi, uefi, thinkpad, screen-recorder

I have a Thinkpad T14s with an AMD cPU. I am trying to record the screen on the laptop from the moment it's powered on: its UEFI BIOS and everything. I know that it can be done using an HDMI capture device. I have one too, but when I can't configure it to output to the main LCD and clone to HDMI simultaneously.

There is an option in BIOS to chose a display, but it only lets you chose 1. It also says that it will clone to every type c display, but I don't have a type c recorder and it still doesn't say that it will clone to the main display. Also, I have seen people do it with an HDMI recorder and the same model of Thinkpad on youtube.

I know that I can connect 2 displays, but it is still uncomfortable, I want specifically to use a built-in LCD.

Comment: Some have tried to do what you want, most ended up using a camera.

Comment: https://youtu.be/pZO_t4n-_kE
He is doing that with a precise model of ThinkPad I have. But all he says that he is using an HDMI capture device. I did ask him in the comments, but it might take a while for him to see my comment.

Comment: Explaining what you've tried so far, and what sort of HDMI capture device you have, will make this a better question.

Comment: HDMI capture device is irrelevant in that problem. Assume I am just using HDMI display. I wanted Thinkpad to output simultaneously to built in display and HDMI. I tried setting display option to HDMI in UEFI BIOS, then it only outputs to HDMI. I also tried to use USB C adapter to HDMI, and that didn't help either. I works fine after boot, but not during boot.